# Struggling to make multiple infowindows within google map

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have read through [Google Maps API v3 multiple markers Infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916158/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-infowindow) and other similar posts.

I have multiple map markers generated from an array of postcodes, the information I need to put within the infowindows come from another array. The way I understand it is the loop is getting what I'm asking for once the loop has completed instead of getting it for each iteration. My two arrays are below:

```
var postcodes = ["postcode1", "postcode2", "postcode3", "postcode4"];
var placenames = ["placename1","placename2","placename3","placename4"];
```

The map is generated the normal way, the markers are placed on the map using the below loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: placenames[i]
    });
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': postcodes[i]
    }, function(results, status) {
        if(status == 'OK') {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: "<?php echo $view->getThemePath();?>/images/map-marker.png",
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

What I thought would happen is that for each iteration of [i] an infowindow and marker would be created. But what's actually happening is that 4 markers are placed on the map for each postcode, each with an infowindow opened when the click event is triggered but the placename within the infowindow is always the last placename.

I understand that there are issues with closures, I've attempted to wrap the marker.addListener within a function, that didn't work. I attempted to loop through each placename within the postcodes loop and that printed out 16 placenames.

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong, it's not completely about the answer I need to understand too so that I'm not repeating the mistake as I have to expand on this map for another project at work.

Comment: geocode is asynchronous, so when it returns the result, the loop has progressed (thus, the infowindow is different - not corresponding to the current position/ marker).

Comment: try creating a function for geocoding and passing the current postcode and the infowindow as parameters.  `var geocode = function(postcode, infowindow){ // do the geocoding as you are now doing};`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. `Uncaught ReferenceError: placeNames is not defined`

Comment: Apologies @geocodezip I'm not sure if I can do that. My map gets its markers and titles from a database thats generated by the client. I tried to sanitize it making manual arrays to illustrate the problem...

The values that go into the map will always change, because they're based on what the client has input at any given time.

So for this case just consider placenames[i] as an example of the placenames array above it.

The best I can provide is a semi-working example of the site. http://merit.frank-digital.co.uk/index.php/key-contacts

Comment: Provide test data (and test code that actually works).  In any case this is a duplicate of many other questions, one of which is [Google Maps infowindow don't work on marker click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301044/google-maps-infowindow-dont-work-on-marker-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function closure on the geocode operation to keep the reference to `i` in the marker click listener function.

proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guL9vL0b/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var postcodes = ["CH44 0, UK", "BN41 1", "DL1 3, UK", "E10 5, UK"];
var placenames = ["placename1", "placename2", "placename3", "placename4"];

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: placenames[i]
    });
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': postcodes[i]
    }, (function(i) { // function closure on i
      return function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(placenames[i])
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      }
    })(i));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: So basically because the idea is that [i] was being used incorrectly?

So the reference to i was being overridden for each iteration?

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, when its callback function runs, the loop has completed, and the infowindow is left containing the last value. (also the reason this code will only work for approximately 10 postcodes, you will hit the rate limit)

Comment: Thanks I think I get it. So basically this isn't a good solution for the client if there is a rate limit. 

Back to the drawing board.